# Data delimited by space key

Tags: c++, cin

I've been assigned a problem I simply do not understand.  I know that I need to use a cin function (like cin.get()), but I'm not sure which one I need or how to use it in this circumstance.

I need to create an insertion and extraction operator that reads (and writes) 3 pieces of data.  All of the data is of the type int. For context, the data is the whole part of a fraction, the numerator, and the denominator.  The data needs to be delimited by spaces, and the operators will be used for file input and output.

What I really want to know is which cin function I should use, and what the particular syntax should be considering I want to store the value in an integer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `cin`, you can just read data using something like this:

```
int wholepart,numer,denom;
cin>>wholepart>>numer>>denom;
```

This would read 3 integers into `wholepart`, `numer` and `denom` respectively. It will skip over whitespace separating the integers.

Answer (score 1):

The normal `operator>>` for `int`s expects the data to be separated by whitespace, so you should be able to just use it and interpret the results as you see fit.